# Why is the following class template matching not ambiguous?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <class T> struct is_rvalue_ref      : std::false_type {};
template <class T> struct is_rvalue_ref<T&&> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T> bool is_rvalue_ref_func(T){return false;}
template <typename T> bool is_rvalue_ref_func(T&&){return true;}

class A {};

int main() 
{
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << is_rvalue_ref<A>::value << '\n';
  std::cout << is_rvalue_ref<A&>::value << '\n';
  std::cout << is_rvalue_ref<A&&>::value << '\n';

  /*****THIS FAILS TO COMPILE************
  A a;
  A& alv = a;
  A&& arv = std::move(a);
  std::cout << is_rvalue_ref_func(a) << '\n';
  std::cout << is_rvalue_ref_func(alv) << '\n';
  std::cout << is_rvalue_ref_func(arv) << '\n';
  **************************************/   

  return 0;
}
```

The compiler(`clang 3.5 -std=c++11`) has no trouble disambiguating the calls to `is_rvalue_ref` while it balks on the `is_rvalue_ref_func` overloads with:

```
rv.cpp:31:16: error: call to 'is_rvalue_ref_func' is ambiguous
  std::cout << is_rvalue_ref_func(a) << '\n';
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
rv.cpp:8:6: note: candidate function [with T = A]
bool is_rvalue_ref_func(T)
     ^
rv.cpp:14:6: note: candidate function [with T = A &]
bool is_rvalue_ref_func(T&&)
     ^
rv.cpp:32:16: error: call to 'is_rvalue_ref_func' is ambiguous
  std::cout << is_rvalue_ref_func(alv) << '\n';
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
rv.cpp:8:6: note: candidate function [with T = A]
bool is_rvalue_ref_func(T)
     ^
rv.cpp:14:6: note: candidate function [with T = A &]
bool is_rvalue_ref_func(T&&)
     ^
rv.cpp:33:16: error: call to 'is_rvalue_ref_func' is ambiguous
  std::cout << is_rvalue_ref_func(arv) << '\n';
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
rv.cpp:8:6: note: candidate function [with T = A]
bool is_rvalue_ref_func(T)
     ^
rv.cpp:14:6: note: candidate function [with T = A &]
bool is_rvalue_ref_func(T&&)
     ^
3 errors generated.
```

However, according to `14.5.5.2 [temp.class.order]`

> For two class template partial specializations, the first is at least
>   as specialized as the second if, given the following rewrite to two
>   function templates, the first function template is at least as
>   specialized as the second according to the ordering rules for function
>   templates (14.5.6.2):
>
> — the first function template has the same
>   template parameters as the first partial specialization and has a
>   single function parameter whose type is a class template
>   specialization with the template arguments of the first partial
>   specialization, and
>
> — the second function template has the same
>   template parameters as the second partial specialization and has a
>   single function parameter whose type is a class template
>   specialization with the template arguments of the second partial
>   specialization.

In the above example, the `is_rvalue_ref_func` overloads are obtained by performing precisely this rewrite of the `is_rvalue_ref` primary template and partial specialization. Why is the function call ambiguous but the class template matching well-defined?

Comment: Function templates are not partially specialized. Instead, they are overloaded and there are two equally good overloads. Note, you can't partially specialize function template, you can only fully specialize them.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Agreed. Fixed the imprecise title. The function templates shown in the example are just overloads. However, they are generated according to the class template matching rules quoted in the question.

Comment: the text you quoted talks about "class specializations". The are 1. full specializations using the arguments provided to the class template, 2. they are classes. You code for the function templates does neither of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the above example, the `is_rvalue_ref_func` overloads are obtained by
>   performing precisely this rewrite of the `is_rvalue_ref` primary
>   template and partial specialization.

Hardly.

> the first function template has the same template parameters as the
>   first partial specialization and has a single function parameter whose
>   type is **a class template specialization with the template arguments of
>   the first partial specialization**

The correct rewrite, given a class template `template<class> class SomeTemplate;`, is

```
template<class T> void is_rvalue_ref_func(SomeTemplate<T>);
template<class T> void is_rvalue_ref_func(SomeTemplate<T&&>);
```

Answer (score 3):

Partial specializations are automatically preferred over primary ones if they are matching. [temp.class.spec.match]/1:

> When a class template is used in a context that requires an
>   instantiation of the class, it is necessary to determine whether the
>   instantiation is to be generated using the primary template or one of
>   the partial specializations. This is done by matching the template
>   arguments of the class template specialization with the template
>   argument lists of the partial specializations.
>
> (1.1) — **If exactly one matching specialization is found, the
>   instantiation is generated from that specialization.**

For the function call, partial ordering kicks in though - and it ignores references for purposes of argument deduction, [temp.deduct.partial]/5:

> Before the partial ordering is done, certain transformations are
>   performed on the types used for partial ordering:
>
> (5.1) — If `P` is a reference type, `P` is replaced by the type
>   referred to.

... which makes the function templates equivalent for partial ordering. Thus the call is ambiguous.

Comment: Ah ok. Further question - why is the behaviour of class template matching different from the "universal reference" matching behaviour you see with something like `template <typename T> void func(T&&);`? Why doesn't an lvalue reference(`A&`) get matched with the `template <class T> struct is_rvalue_ref<T&&>` specialization with `T` being deduced to be `A&`, as it would with functions?

Comment: @Pradhan Because there's a crucial difference, conceptually, between template argument deduction  for partial specializations and function templates. It's hard to explain, but the latter is just far more "relaxed".

Comment: Could you point me to the relevant sections perhaps? I agree that the behaviour in my code snippet is not counter-intuituve. But I am unable to deduce it from the standard :)

Comment: @Pradhan a good article on this topic is this: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Comment: @pepper_chico Thanks! But function template specializations aren't part of this discussion at all. It is function overload resolution vs class template specialization matching. However, `14.5.5.2` sort of equates these two.

Comment: @Pradhan Forwarding references are enabled by [temp.deduct.call]/3, which are rules for function template calls only.

Comment: @Pradhan The associated paragraph (14.5.6.2) is the one that contains the rules for ordering of function templates. The one you show doesn't, it mentions functions templates so that one understands how ordering of class specialization works.

Answer (score 0):

The function templates are not partially specialized. Your quote only applies to partial class template specialization. It uses the rules for function overload resolution to define which specialization is more specialized.

Instead, the function templaes are overloaded and there are two equally good overloads. Note, you can't partially specialize function template, you can only fully specialize them.

If you want to use a function template to determine if something is an rvalue you could do something like this (I think; currently I can't easily test the code):

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_rvalue_func(T&&) {
    return !std::is_reference<T>::value;
}
```

I don't think you can distinguish between rvalues and rvalue references being passed to the function, though. That is, I think both of these will yield `true` although only the latter is actually an rvalue reference to an object:

```
is_rvalue_func(int());
int i(17);
is_rvalue_func(std:move(i));
```